# enumerate through all IEnumerables

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I need to send different IEnumerables to an `Printer` object.
This printer object will then do something to them, inside a foreach loop.

```
class Printer
{
    public Printer(IEnumerable list)
    {
        foreach (var enumerable in list)
        {
            //DO STUFF
        }
    }
}
```

This lets me send any enumerable, such as an `List<T>` to the printer object.
such as

```
    var list = new List<string> {"myList"};
    new Printer(list); //mylist
```

This works fine.
BUT if I send a `Dictionary<T, T>` such as:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> {{1, "mydict"}};
new Printer(dictionary); //[1, mydict]
```

It'll have a key and a value. What I would want though, would be separate access to the `Value` property inside the `foreach` loop. All I DO have access to is the enumerable object, which has no properties I can use.

Now what if the datatype T is an object containing several properties (this goes for both examples). How would I be able to use these properties in my foreach loop?

Do I honestly have to create an overload of the constructor, foreach possible datatype I might send down to it?

Also, all I need to do in the foreach is not dependable to any datatypes - as it won't manipulate everything. I do need ACCESS to all the properties though.

Also, this is just example code, not actually the production-code I use in my application.

Comment: Wouldn't you have the same problem in the first example?  After all you could get a List<T> where T is a complex object containing several properties?

Comment: Are you sure that it accepts IEnumerable and not IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: Yes, that is what I clumsily tried to explain in the "Now what if the" paragraph.
I'll try to edit my post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you change the code of the Printer class? If it accepted something like an `IEnumerable<IPrintable>` instead of just an `IEnumerable` it would be easier. With an interface like this:

```
interface IPrintable
{
    void Print();
}
```

Then all objects that would be sent to the `Printer` would need to implement that interface. Then you could do:

```
class Printer
{
    public Printer(IEnumerable<IPrintable> list)
    {
        foreach (var enumerable in list)
        {
            enumerable.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

And if you have a dictionary of printable objects, something like:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int,IPrintable>();
```

You could just pass the values to the function:

```
var printer = new Printer(dict.Values);
```

Comment: It seems like a clever solution! I'll let the thread live for a couple of hours. If no one trumps yours solution, I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 4):

You could modify your method to accept a delegate that returns the data the print method needs.  Something like this:

```
// You will not need this class, if you always want a single string result.
class PrinterData
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    // More properties?
}
class Printer
{
    public Printer<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, PrinterData> func)
    {
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            PrinterData data = func(item);
            // Do something with the data.
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] ints = new int[] {1,2,3};
new Printer().Print(ints, x => new PrinterData() { Value = x.ToString() });

var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> {{1, "mydict"}};
new Printer().Print(dictionary, x => new PrinterData() { Value = x.Name + " = " + x.Value });
```

Per Erik Stendahl's answer is very similar.

Answer (score 3):

You have to extract an enumerable with the values you want to pass before you call new Printer(). In the case of the dictionary this is simple: just use dict.Values. A more general case is:

```
var list = List<MyObject>()...

var printer = new Printer(list.Select(x => x.MyProperty));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to treat different types differently, you probably should make different methods.  If you want to treat them the same, you should accept a common interface, and only use the methods defined for the interface.

It would be possible to do

```
if (list is Dictionary<int, string>) {
    // do special case
}
```

but I shudder at the thought.

You can even check generically:

```
class Printer<T>
{
    public Printer<T>(IEnumerable list)
    {
        foreach (var enumerable in list)
        {
            if (list is Dictionary<T, T>) {
                //DO STUFF
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I shudder at that thought as well

Comment: Is there anyway to check if list is a dictionary<T,T>?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a collection, though it is enumerable, can hold different types of objects, as you saw with the difference between the `List` and the `Dictionary`.

To get around this without coding for each object type, you'd have to only accept an enumerable collection of a certain type that you define, for example `IEnumerable<IMyType>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do anything at the callee, it's up to the caller to make sure it passes an `IEnumerable` that is "valid" for Printer, like passing `dictionary.Values` instead of `dictionary` in your example. However if the class is public and will be used by 3rd party users, you're better to add some generic constraint to your `IEnumerable`, as others stated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result:
I used your guys help, so I guess I shouldn't vote my own as the answer.

```
class Printer
{
    public Printer(IEnumerable<IPrintable> list) //Accepts any collection with an object that implements IPrintable interface
    {
        foreach (var enumerable in list) //iterate through list of objects
        {
            foreach (var printable in enumerable)//loops through properties in current object
            {
                //DO STUFF 
            }
        }
    }
}

interface IPrintable : IEnumerable { }
class SomeObject : IPrintable
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public interface IEnumerable
    {
        IEnumerator GetEnumerator(); //Returns a Enumerator
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        yield return Property1;
        yield return Property2;
    }
}
```

I'd naturally need to implement custom GetEnumerator() foreach object - no problem though!